# Unable to link two portals in the immersive portals mod in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In Minecraft, I was using the Immersive Portals mod and I can not get two of the portals to connect, it is connecting to where a different portal is, but there are no portal helpers there. I know it can auto-generate portals but it didn't for that one... They *are* facing different directions but they are the only two portals in my world. I would like to know a way to fix this, or better a command to directly link two portals without having to play this guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

They will only connect if they are the same shape. They don't have to be the same size, but they need to have the same proportions.